# Gradle/JUnit imbalanced test assignments to parallel forks

Tags: java, gradle

Gradle version: 4.6
Language: Java
Test Framework: JUnit4

I have a project with > 600 tests in about 120 test classes. The test distribution among the classes is very imbalanced. Some of the test classes have big numbers of tests and are slow.

The problem is: I configured {maxParallelForks = 4}. For my project, Gradle happened to **assign several of the longest running tests to the same fork**. That one process ends up running alone and takes about half of the time of the entire build.

I imagine if I can tweak the test assignments to the forks (I don't need absolute control. I just want to disturb the current assignments), my build time can be greatly shortened.

I have tried using a different # of forks and seen improvement. But if I want to keep my parallel=4, is there any way I can modify the test assignments?

Thanks.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2669
It seems like they want us to buy paid product in order to have proper distribution :P